# Can we say "The many books have included this topic."?

Tags: articles

I tried to search in Google of the combinational expressions of 'The many things' and "the many books", and I found most of cases these expressions are followed by an attributive clause, like:

> The many things people got wrong
>
> Thank You for the Many Things You've Done

I suspected that "The many books have included this topic." (without modifier) is wrong, and the article 'the' is redundant here. Can anyone further explain the reason behind, or share different understandings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern is:

the + noun + restrictive clause

> The many items sold on eBay...
>
> The few birds we saw today...
>
> The thousands of students pouring into Ft. Lauderdale...

This pattern can even be extended to proper names:

> The John Monroe I knew in college would never have said that.

P.S. *Attributive* usually means *before* the noun.

Comment: So can we say "The many items have been sold on eBay."?

Comment: No, only "The many items _that_ have been sold on e Bay." There has to be a restrictive relative clause.

Comment: Thanks KarlG for the answer. It clarified my doubt. BTW: I think 'attributive clause' is the correct expression which can be found a lot when googling it.